# How to start containerd node local container images in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

I want to start node local container image which is managed by containerd.

from seeing `ctr images list`, there exist node local images

```
REF                                                                                                                     TYPE                                                 DIGEST                                                                  SIZE     PLATFORMS   LABELS
cuda                                                                                                                    application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:6c2570b465eb3c03c2b892520bfb59ec9347c45dcfcf557b2c0ba03a27fba378 44.6 MiB linux/amd64 -
docker.io/library/hello-world:latest                                                                                    application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:fa68d054b0a8f55613c10f2db5c6617286dd30fde5607d2824ed9fb283e23043 16.8 KiB linux/amd64 -
docker.io/nvidia/cuda:11.0-base                                                                                         application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:6c2570b465eb3c03c2b892520bfb59ec9347c45dcfcf557b2c0ba03a27fba378 44.6 MiB linux/amd64 -
```

I make following yaml with adding `imagePullPolicy: Never` and failed with
Of course, I omit `imagePullPolicy: Never`, it works fine.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cuda-vectoradd
spec:
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
  - name: cuda-vectoradd
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    image: "cuda"
    resources:
#      limits:
#         nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

Failed case, error messages are follows.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------             ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled          24m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/cuda-vectoradd to testserver
  Warning  Failed             22m (x12 over 24m)    kubelet            Error: ErrImageNeverPull
  Warning  ErrImageNeverPull  4m42s (x97 over 24m)  kubelet            Container image "cuda" is not present with pull policy of Never
```

Is there any method to load node local image for containerd?
Any comments are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your pod manifest is wrong. Image is not `cuda` but `docker.io/nvidia/cuda:11.0-base`. The whole string should be included.
So:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cuda-vectoradd
spec:
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
  - name: cuda-vectoradd
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    image: docker.io/nvidia/cuda:11.0-base
...
```

Since `docker.io` is the default image repository, you can omit it in the string.

```yaml
image: nvidia/cuda:11.0-base
```

is sufficient enough.